# Django unclear 404

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-404, django-class-based-views

EDIT : Found the solution myself !

This is what I did. I'm pretty sure it's not a best practice, but it worked for me.

```py
class CommentCreateView(CreateView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = {'form': CommentForm()}
        return render(request, 'news/add_comment_to_article.html', context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            article = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=kwargs.get('pk'))
            print(article)
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = article
            comment.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('news:article', kwargs={'article_id': article.pk}))
```

I have a question, after converting my view (included below) from function based view to class based view I keep getting an error (page not found - 404) after trying to submit a comment on an article. Why is that ?

the view now :

```py
class CommentCreateView(RedirectView):
    model = Comment
    form_class = CommentForm
    template_name = 'news/add_comment_to_article.html'

    def form_valid(self, *args, **kwargs):
        article = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=kwargs.get('pk'))
        comment = form.save(commit=False)
        comment.post = article
        comment.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('news:article', kwargs={'article_id': article.pk}))
```

the same view how it used to be, function based (working) :

```py
def add_comment_to_article(request, pk):
    article = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = article
            comment.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('news:article', kwargs={"article_id": article.pk}))
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'news/add_comment_to_article.html', {'form': form})
```

comment form:

```py
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('author', 'text',)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [FormView](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.2/django.views.generic.edit/FormView/) instead of [RedirectView](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.2/django.views.generic.base/RedirectView/). (We can see that `RedirectView` doesn't have `form_valid` method.)

Read more about FormView in [Django's official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormView).

Comment: I tried using CreateView and FormView, but I haven't managed to get results :(

Comment: Then it will be a good opportunity to learn more about one of them in detail!